Aiogram. Replykeyboardmarkup добавление передаваемой кнопкой информации
Пишу бота на aiogram с FSM, кнопки Replykeyboardmarkup.
Кнопки (их названия) формируются из ключей словаря, но мне в следующее состояние нужно передать ещё и соответствующее этому ключу значение.
Возможно, я не могу это правильно загуглить и поэтому прошу помочь.
text = 'aaa', callback_data = 'bbb'

с этими кнопками не работает.

У reply кнопок нет callback_data, это обычные кнопки, которые отправляют текс, написанный на них

Если кто столкнулся с подобным, есть кривое-косое решение:

В состоянии, в котором перебираем ключи словаря для создания кнопок, до перебора этого словаря, объявляем его глобальным.

В следующем состоянии, получив ключ из нажатой кнопки, читаем объявленный глобальным словарь, и по ключу забираем значение.


